# ActiveRecord decrement not working in test

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Rails 5.1.6 application I created an `Attendance` model association between users and events so that users can participate to a given event. Events have an integer `seats` attribute that is decremented each time a participation is created. The Attendance controller is:

```
before_action :logged_in_user
before_action :participants_limit, only: :create

def create
  @attendance = current_user.attendances.build(attendance_params)
  if @attendance.save
    @event.decrement(:seats)
    flash[:success] = "Congratulation! Your participation has been recorded."
    redirect_back(fallback_location: root_url)
  else
    flash[:danger] = @event.errors.full_messages.join(', ')
    redirect_back(fallback_location: root_url)
  end
end


private

    def attendance_params
      params.require(:attendance).permit(:event_id)
    end

    def participants_limit
      @event = Event.find(params[:attendance][:event_id])
      if @event.seats == 0
        flash[:danger] = 'Attention! Unfortunately this event is full!'
        redirect_back(fallback_location: root_url)
      end
    end
```

I would like to test the create action of the `Attendance` controller, so I created the following test:

```
def setup
  @event = events(:event_1)
  @user = users(:user_12)
end

test "should redirect create when participants limit reached" do
  assert @event.participants.count == 2
  assert @event.seats == 5
  participants = (1..5).map do |num|
    users("user_#{num}".to_sym)
  end
  participants.each do |user|
    log_in_as(user)
    post attendances_path, params: { attendance: { user_id: user.id, event_id: @event.id } }
  end
  assert @event.participants.count == 7
  assert @event.seats == 0
  log_in_as(@user)
  assert_no_difference 'Attendance.count' do
    post attendances_path, params: { attendance: { user_id: @user.id, event_id: @event.id } }
  end
  assert_redirected_to root_url
end
```

The test fails at the line `assert @event.seats == 0`: seats are not decremented and result still 5: why is that? I wonder why the decrement method is not working, and if there is something am I missing in the test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `@event` is cached in memory and controllers change corresponding database record.

use `@record.reload.seats` in tests when you expect it to have just changed - this reloads record from database.

Also keep in mind that your code is vulnerable to a race condition if two participants will try to register at the same time, wrap whole check-change code block in `event.with_lock` to mitigate that.

Comment: There are still 5 seats, even after I added reload

Comment: @Asarluhi add an assert around `post` to ensure participant is created successfully, there may be a failed validation

Comment: The line `assert @event.participants.count == 7` results true, so the participants are created, their number change from 2 to 7

Comment: @Asarluhi use `decrement!` (with a bang) or save `@event` after change

Comment: The bang does not work. If I save the event, strangely one seat remains. This is very odd. I tried to add more participants, and no matter what the number is always 1 seat remains.

Comment: @Asarluhi it's already closer, but there're 2 hard things in programming: cache invalidation, naming things and off-by-1 errors :))

Comment: It turns out that `decrement!` with a bang along with `reload` in `assert @event.reload.seats == 0' was the solution